# Between last line of a while loop and the first line of re-entry of a while loop, variable seems to change/disappear

Tags: python

Stuck on LeetCode problem 94. Binary Tree Inorder Traversal (Python).

Here is the problem

https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/description/

My issue is, at the last line inside a while loop, there is clearly a node assigned to variable 'node'. But on the very first line, it says nothing is assigned to variable 'node'. Also, this only seems to happen after a few loops through the while loop. What could be happening between the first line and the last line? For the first few loops, the value of 'node' is exactly the same between the first line and last line of the while loop. On the 3rd time, a change occurs.

Here is the solution I can up so far

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[int]
        """

        res = []
        rootTrack = []
        rootCovered = []


        rootTrack.append(root)
        i=0
        while rootTrack:
            print('right after while loop re-enter', root.val)
            while root.left and root.left not in rootCovered:
                root = root.left
                print('left value ', root.val)
                rootTrack.append(root)
            if len(rootTrack) > 0:
                root = rootTrack.pop() 
                res.append(root.val)  
                rootCovered.append(root)
                print('pop value ', root.val)
            if root.right and root.right not in rootCovered:
                root = root.right
                print('right value ', root.val)
                rootTrack.append(root)
            print('final before while loop re-enter ', root.val)
        return res
```

Here is the error message it gives me

> Line 23: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'

which refers to this line of code

`print('right after while loop re-enter', root.val)`

Here is the stdout

```
right after while loop re-enter 1
pop value  1
right value  2
final before while loop re-enter  2
right after while loop re-enter 2
left value  3
pop value  3
final before while loop re-enter  3
right after while loop re-enter 3
pop value  2
final before while loop re-enter  2
```

From the print statements, you can tell that there is a node assigned to variable `node` on the very last line in the `while` loop, but at the very first line, that's when I get the error saying that there is nothing assigned to variable `node`.

What could happen before the last line of the while loop at the very first line of the next round?

Comment: The only thing that happens in between is checking `rootTrack`... However, are you sure that the loop did not finis there and that you did not then call function `inorderTraversal` again? Add another print before `while`...

Comment: Theoretically, reading `root.val` could delete `root.val`, so you could not read it again, but that is really highly unlikely :\

Comment: So I put a print statement right before the while loop, and it just prints that statement, but now it's not printing anything else; it's not printing any other print statements. . . very weird.

Comment: Gah, I see the issue. It kept on printing out all the test cases on leetcode. And one of the cases was not inputting a new node. I wouldn't have found this out unless you suggested putting a print statement before the while loop. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @zvone 's suggestion of putting a print statement before the while loop, I was able to figure out  It kept on printing out all the test cases on leetcode. And one of the cases was not inputting a new node. I wouldn't have found this out unless you suggested putting a print statement before the while loop.